# html 5 css stickman example

Tags: html

Trying to draw a basic stick man in html 5 css that walks. If anyone has any sample code that achieves this or can point me to a tutorial that does I would be grateful. (please note I have seen the tutorials on drawing shapes)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sencha animator](http://www.sencha.com/products/animator/download.php) gives a GUI similar to Flash for animating in HTML5 with CSS3. Should make life a lot easier.

Comment: I appreciate the recommendation I installed it, but not having much luck getting it to load in 32 bit windows 7. Any ideas?

Comment: Broken link. Try modify this if you want in pure CSS: https://codepen.io/lorayoconnell/pen/pyayOP